# Querying one delegate twice for one event

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I was recently asked a question what will happen if I would query one handler twice. Let me just show you code:

```
 public delegate void OpenEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

 public class MyWindow
 {
     public event OpenEventHandler Open;

     public void OpenWindow()
     {
         if (Open != null)
         {
             Open(this, new EventArgs());
         }
     }
 }

 public class TwoDelegates
 {
     public static void HandleOpen(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Birds fly");
         (sender as MyWindow).Open -= HandleOpen;
     }

     public static void Run()
     {
         var window = new MyWindow();
         window.Open += HandleOpen;
         window.Open += HandleOpen;

         window.OpenWindow();
         Console.ReadKey();
     }
 }
```

I wonder why string is still printed twice. On the beginning of it Invocation list consist of two items with same delegate reference, but after a first run it is cleaned up, still the secon invocaiton appears.

**Update1:**

Seems that even simple `-=` removes only one entry:

```
 var window = new MyWindow();

 window.Open += HandleOpen;
 window.Open += HandleOpen;

 Console.WriteLine(window.getHandlers().Count());
 window.Open -= HandleOpen;
 Console.WriteLine(window.getHandlers().Count());
```

Though debug mode in VS2010, while you look through `window.Open` internal properties shows  empty invocation list with 0 count. Seems that it's some magic in debug info displayed in VS.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of how the delegate fires the event handlers.  It takes a copy of the internal delegate list before it begins firing it off.  As a result, adding or removing event handlers for an event inside of an event handler for that same event only affects future invocations of that event, not the current invocation.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit detailed. I'm basically trying to clean invocaiton list of original event via sending accessing sender object. And first `-=` really cleans invocation list of `sender as Window` objects `Open.NonPublic.InvocationsList` property, it's even diplayed in debug window. But `GetInvocationList()` still return one handler.

Comment: @Johnny_D The whole point of this answer is that that doesn't matter.  Clearing the invocation list will only affect which handlers are run when the event is invoked in the future.  It's too late to change which handlers will be run in the current invocation of the event as the invocation list is copied when it is invoked.

Comment: ok, that's clear. But still I want to know what happens beside the scene, why VS2010 behaves this way displaying empty invocation list, though GetInvocationList returns one entry.

Comment: Ahhh, do you mean that `GetInvocationList` returns a cloned instance?

Comment: @Johnny_D Well, as I can't see exactly what you're doing it's hard to say what is a clone of what, but one was likely cloned from the other at some point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Servy said, here's a slightly modified version of your code, with some debugging helpers to clarify what's going on. In the HandleOpen function, we examine the event handlers before and after removing HandleOpen from the event. The summary is: There's two copies of HandleOpen in your multicast, there's no reason for a single Open-=HandleOpen to remove both of them.

```
public class MyWindow
{
    public event OpenEventHandler Open;

    public void OpenWindow()
    {
        if (Open != null)
        {
            Open(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public Delegate[] getHandlers()
    {
        return Open.GetInvocationList();
    }
}

public class TwoDelegates
{
    public static void HandleOpen(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Birds fly");
        var thisWin = sender as MyWindow;
        var before = thisWin.getHandlers();

        (sender as MyWindow).Open -= HandleOpen;
        var after = thisWin.getHandlers();

    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        var window = new MyWindow();
        window.Open += HandleOpen;
        window.Open += HandleOpen;

        window.OpenWindow();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that even if `HandleOpen` had the `-= HandleOpen` twice it still would fire the second handler.  This is an entirely different issue, that removing the handler only removes one of the two instances, not both.

Comment: This is absolutely true -- The callee can't modify the copy of the in-flight event.

Comment: Based on the OP's comments, it sounds like that's what he's trying to do.  Now, it also seems like he thinks a single `-=` will remove both handlers, so this answer is indeed helpful.

Comment: I focused on OP's statement that "On the beginning of it Invocation list consist of two items with same delegate reference, but after a first run it is cleaned up" and thought, well no, it's not cleaned up how you seem to think it might be cleaned up.

Comment: @ReacherGilt, I've set brake point after removing `HandleOpen` and saw an empty invocation list on `sender` object, by going to base -> NonPublic -> Invocation list -> was `null`. Thought `getHandlers` returned one. That's what I didn't understand.